# Google Maps JavaScript API v3 editable polygon, prevent complex polygon (intersecting polylines)

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Using the Google Maps JavaScript v3 API's editable polygons and/or drawing library, is it possible to somehow prevent the user from creating complex polygons where two or more of the containing polylines intersect each other? Or am I going to have to write my own polygon editing library if I want this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for polyline intersection in the DrawingManager's `polygoncomplete` event. It will pass in the polygon as an argument, then it is up to you to detect/fix polyline intersections.

Comment: Yeah that was my backup plan. Do you know if there's any way to easily access the temporary polylines that DrawingManager creates while you're actually drawing the polygon, before it is complete and the polygoncomplete event is fired? I would like to be able to check for intersections in real-time as a new vertice is being added or an existing one dragged and then cancel that individual operation before it is even applied to the polygon. This behavior is important because there's no elegant way to "fix" one of these polygons after the fact.